# Symfony2: check select is not empty

Tags: symfony, validation

I am trying to validate manually a form, from the form itself (this is a dynamic form).

Checking if mandatory values are set, it is working great with input:

```
$constraints[] = new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'Please enter something'));
$params['constraints'] = $constraints;
...
$formBuilder->add($field, $type, $params);
```

However this does not working with select ('choices'). What is the correct constraint?

Answer (score 2):

For a choice field contraint object should be `NotNull` and not `NotBlank`.

```
$constraints[] = new Assert\NotNull(array('message' => 'Please enter something'));
$params['constraints'] = $constraints;
...
$formBuilder->add($field, $type, $params);
```

---

### NotNull

> Validates that a value is not strictly equal to null. To ensure that a
>   value is simply not blank (not a blank string), see the NotBlank
>   constraint.

From: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html

---

### NotBlank

> Validates that a value is not blank, defined as not equal to a blank
>   string and also not equal to null. To force that a value is simply not
>   equal to null, see the NotNull constraint.

From: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html

---